# What is the difference between the control channels BCCH AND FCCH in GSM?

Tags: mobile, gsm, telecommunication

BCCH > Broadcast Control Channel
FCCH > Frequency Correction Channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BCCH**

Network uses this channel to constantly broadcast messages to all device into that cell coverage.

System Information messages are transmitted in this channel. Those messages carry network/cell identity as well re-selection criteria, neighbor cells information and several other info.

It's a downlink only channel.

More Info:

http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/GSM-BCCH-Broadcast-Control-Channel.html

**FCCH**

In this channel, network sends specific data which is used by the mobile station for synchronization purposes.  Based on this change, mobile can syncronize its frequency to that used by Base Station.

That specific data is a "all zeros" burst which produces continuous sine wave which has some dependency with RF centre frequency of that cell. Due to this dependency, it helps the Mobile to get synchronized with the cell.

It's a downlink only channel.

It is sent during BCCH Timeslot allows the mobile to synchronize its own frequency to that of the transmitting cell.

**SCH**

Synchronization Channel (SCH) is also used for synchronization purposes. However, it is more related to TDMA frame structure than the frequency. This channel carries the Synchronization Channel Information.

It is also send during BCCH TimeSlot.

**Registration Procedure**

All of those channels are Broadcast Channels

When device is trying to acquire service from a network, the first step is find the FCCH All-Zero burst. After that, it can assume the position of SCH and find it as well.

After finding FCCH and SCH, it can now find the BCCH and receive all Broadcasted information.

Comment: Thank you, but is FCCH related to the Broadcast control channel? FCCH adjust the mobile crystal to to the the base station but I know that this happens in the SCH the synchronization channel and it's a down link channel.

Comment: Before capture the SCH, devices must find the FCCH. After device detect a FCCH Burst (148 Zeros), it then, try to find the SCH and later, the BCCH

Comment: @GuilhermeP  Very nice answer. It might be worth clarifying that the term Mobile Station means the device connecting to the network (i.e. a phone or computer and dongle) rather than part of the network itself. This often causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In GSM-850 you have channels 128–251, which is 124 channels. The highest channel uplink is at the lowest frequency in the band, and the downlink is at a positive offset of 45MHz from the downlink. A channel consists of an uplink and a downlink frequency.

There is typically a frequency reuse factor of 1/4, where 4 is the number of cells in the cluster, this means that each cell can have 124/4 = 31 frequencies. The minimum ARFCN assignment granularity for MNOs is therefore 4 i.e. one frequency reuse group per cluster, which gives one frequency (channel) per cell. Each cluster defines channels n to n + cluster size, where each cell in the cluster is assigned a channel based on the position of the cell in the cluster, and n is the frequency reuse group. The reuse factor multiplied by the reuse factor tells you how many reuse groups there are, which tells you how many channels there are in a cell within the cluster.

The difference between frequency and channel is that they are assigned a channel, and each channel has a carrier frequency which is used to carry data within the channel, so they can be used interchangeably.

When using directional instead of omnidirectional antennas, the BTSs are not in the middle of the cells but at 3 of the vertices:

[image]

I modified the Wikipedia diagram to show a cell in green, the sectors of the cell in red and the neighbouring cells in blue. In this case, the neighbouring cells form a cluster, with a reuse factor of 3/7. This is 7 cells per cluster and 3 sectors per cell. It's 3/7 because we get 3 frequencies per cell in the reuse group of size 21 because we have 3 sectors per cell. The minimum granularity of assignment to an MNO is once again the cluster size in cells, or the reuse group magnitude divided by 3, which gives 1 antenna (and 1 frequency on that antenna) per cell.

This frequency would have to contain the MNO's FCCH-SCH-BCCH sequence, and if they are assigned 3 frequencies per cell i.e. a full reuse group then only one of the channels needs to contain the FCCH-SCH-BCCH. Mobiles scan all channels sensing for the FCCH burst and once they lock on to that, they can receive the SCH at the start of the next TDMA frame, and then the BCCH which at the start of the 3rd TDMA frame. The FCCH may only be sent during timeslot 0 on the frequency that carries the frame with the FCCH-SCH-BCCH sequence, and therefore it acts as a flag to the mobile to identify timeslot 0. It has a sequence of 148 zeros.

The BCCH uses a [special layer 2 packet](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/74052/54670) as opposed to LAPDm that consists of (as opposed to encapsulates) an RR [System Information (SI) Type message.](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/GSM-system-information-messages.html) As there are several SI message types having a different content, it is useful for the MS to know where these types of messages are located in a group of multiframes. [Each type of SI message is associated with a TC value](http://etutorials.org/Mobile+devices/gprs+mobile+internet/Chapter+5+Radio+Interface+RLC+MAC+Layer/Broadcast+Information+Management/). A the SI type 1 messages are sent when TC value is equal to 0. This means that all SI message types are scheduled in the same location within a group of 51-multiframes by any network manufacturer irrespective of operator.

For SI message types broadcast on the BCCH, TC is defined by the formula TC = (FN div 51) mod 8. The FN is the [BCCH slot's frame number in the hyperframe](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/05/0501/05.02.00_60/gsmts_0501v050200p.pdf) (remember hyperframes contain 2048 superframes, which contain 26 control multiframes or 51 traffic multiframes, and control multiframes contain 51 TDMA frames, traffic 26, which contain 8 time slots, which contain a burst, which is one of either a normal, random access, frequency correction or synchronisation burst) div 51 and you get the multiframe. It's therefore sent every 8 multiframes.

SI Type 2 contains the neighbour cell BCCH frequencies (ARFCNs), which means that it does not need to continue scanning for more FCCHs when it finds the first FCCH. SI Type 4 contains the LAI. SI Type 1 contains the ARFCNs that are used in the cell, [and so on](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/GSM-system-information-messages.html). The neighbouring cells are all cells that are physically adjacent, which may include repeat BCCH channel numbers if the cluster size is smaller than the area made up by the physically adjacent cells, which will happen for all neighbouring cells except for the one you are in. This is illustrated below in that the physically adjacent cells outlined in black to the green cell that we are in contain repeat frequencies except for the cell we are in as it is the only cell that is green within the physcially adjacent cells:

[image]

The MS can then read these BCCHs and determine what is the best cell to camp on by measuring the channel gain and bit error rates as well as the recommended transmit power. If GPRS is supported then the SI type 13 BCCH message contains the description of the PBCCH (radio block number, radio channel description, training sequence code, and PR of transmission compared to BCCH).